# Unlock without pressing hard key in android

Tags: android

Can anybody know how to unlock a screen without pressing hard key..? or how to wake a screen without pressing hard key when phone is in locked state.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can set [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to wake up your phone after certain amount of time.

```
setRepeating(int type, long triggerAtTime, long interval, PendingIntent operation)
```